# Machine-learning regression coefficients

Tags: regression, machine-learning, tensorflow

Say I want to do supervised learning of response variable $y_k$ (continuous) and feature variables $(x_k, z_k, a_k, b_k)$ where $k$ is the sample index.

Instead of learning the general form
$$ y \sim f(x, z, a, b),$$
I would like to learn the form
$$ y \sim A(a,b) x + B(a,b) y + C(a,b). $$

This is because the coefficients $A$ and $B$ are more critical than the general (non-linear) form, and I know that the structure of $y, x, z$ is linear, but the coefficients may vary depending on the values of $a$ and $b$.

I am wondering if there is any learning method suitable for this situation.

If I use neural networks for learning $A(a,b)$ and $B(a,b)$, is it possible to optimize the RSS with `tensorflow`? If I design the model with tensorflow, note that the last layer is not a typical NN layer in the sense that the products, $(A, B)$ and $(x,y)$, depends on the feature variables.

Much appreciate your help in advance.